# how to write filename in utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, filenames

I am trying to save the frames in to "veriseti" file but framenames can not be shown regularly.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath)
    sampleNum = 0
    while (True):
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            # incrementing sample number
            sampleNum = sampleNum + 1
            # saving the captured face in the dataset folder TrainingImage

            cv2.imwrite("veriseti\ " + username1 + "." + id1 + '.' + str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include all of your code?  Your last line has an asterisk at the end so it made me wonder.    I don't know what username1 or id1 are but I assume strings, you could wrap those in str(), couldn't hurt.

Comment: Awesome!  I am glad I was able to help you out a little.   Have a nice day.